# New project from existing sources from command line

Tags: intellij-idea, command-line

I recently saw a video where the presenter had a clojure lein project. He typed:

```
> intellij .
```

at the root of the project and a new intellij project was created from those sources. Was that a script he wrote or something that is possible with all Intellij IDEA distros.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by running the following command from your root project:
`idea.exe .`

Just make sure that IntelliJ bin folder is included in your PATH environment variable, or simply provide the full path of the idea executable.